# Split 4-dimensional np.array into 3-dimensional np.arrays by 4th dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, 4d

My apologies if this has been answered elsewhere. I have searched for two days without luck. It seems like a pretty straightforward problem, though I cannot solve it.

I have a 4-dimensional numpy array of shape `(40, 320, 320, 8)`. This array is the output of a convolutional layer of a CNN, where dimension 1 represents outputs for the 40 inputs to the model, dimensions 2 and 3 represent the feature map outputs of a given filter, and dimension 4 represents the 8 filters utilized in the convolutional layer. My python experience is still very novice.

What I am trying to do is split this 4-dimensional array into 8 separate 3-dimensional arrays, where each new array corresponds to one of the 8 filters represented in dimension 4.

Currently, I am able to do this one at a time with the following....

`filter_out =  squeeze(intermediate_output[:,:,:,1])`

How can I do this for all 8 (or n) at once?

Comment: Have you considered doing something like groups = np.moveaxis(intermediate_output, 3, 0). Then you can use groups[0], groups[1], etc.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need a list of arrays, there's no harm in using a straight forward comprehension.

```
alist = [arr[...,i] for i in range(8)]
```

Transposing and wrapping with `list` won't be any faster since `list(...)` just iterates on the first dimension. Array split also iterates taking slices.

No need to `squeeze` - unless using `np.split`.

But do you really need separate arrays?

Answer (score 0):

This will produce a list of the 3-dimensional arrays:

```
list(intermediate_output.transpose(3, 0, 1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility:

```py
split_array_list = [x.squeeze() for x in np.split(my_array, my_array.shape[-1])]
```